No SNI sent from RTMPS client (OBS Studio)
We're trying to deploy an RTMP server on our Kubernetes cluster behind an Istio Api Gateway. All services share one port (443) and Istio terminates the SSL connection and routes each request to the correct service via SNI.
For some reason, this does not work with OBS Studio as a RTMPS Client. With openssl c_connect it worked.
Is it possible that the OBS Studio SSL client does not implement SNI?

It's more likely that OBS doesn't make use of the SNI functionality of the SSL library they are using. It's as simple as not telling it any host name during function call, so it's unable to do SNI. Have you tried to actually capture the SSL handshake and observe what is inside?
